# Checkout matching branch in different repo if it exists or fallback to main

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines-yaml

I have 2 repos with the following repo/branch setup:

```
UI_Repo
- Feature1
- Feature2
- main

API_Repo
- Feature2
- main
```

When I build my UI_Repo I want to checkout the matching API_Repo branch **if it exists** and if it doesn't, fall back to use main which should always exist.

If I have this it'll always use main and fail because new changes in Feature2 need pulled

```
steps:
- checkout: self
- checkout: git://Proj/API_Repo@main
```

If I have this it'll always try for a matching repo, but we don't often change the API, so it's wasted time to create and delete branches that don't add any value.

```
steps:
- checkout: self
- checkout: git://Proj/API_Repo@$(Build.SourceBranch)
```

I essentially want to do pull the Build.SourceBranch and if that fails pull main.

Comment: A good start would be checking out multiple repos:  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/repos/multi-repo-checkout?view=azure-devops  Then you could maybe use "if" statements or "control options".

Comment: @Narthring I can't find anything that would let me check for existence of a branch. If I specify a branch that doesn't exist it just fails.

Comment: I see.  The tasks allow you to continue after the task fails.  I assumed you could attempt to checkout multiple branches and if one failed you could continue forward and evaluate later.

Comment: I found a similar question with a suggestion that you could manage the Git checkout from a Bash script:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70382032/allow-for-failed-checkout-in-azure-devops-yaml